# Display Text (Title of product) instead of long URL

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, joomla

I need to display Title of product instead of its url. For Exapmle instead of

```
localhost/test/index.php?option=com_spidercatalog&product_id=109&view=showproduct&page_num=1&back=1&show_category_details=1&display_type=cube&show_subcategories=1&show_subcategories_products=2&show_products=1&select_categories=1&Itemid=106
```

display localhost/test/catalog/product/257-Sony

Title and ID of post 
P.S. working in joomla

Comment: What you want is seo, you can try the one, which is build in joomla, global settings->turn seo on.

Answer (score 0):

This is URL Rewriting. You have to wrote rules for Apache or Nginx. If you're using Joomla, it can do it for you. More info here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try turn on Joomla seo->turn seo.
Or you can use SEO COMPONENTS such as located in [Joomla extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata).
I recommend using sh404 + plugin to virtuemart.

Comment: But im creating plugin so cant use other one

Comment: You are developing seo plugin?

Comment: There are plenty of plugins free to download, why do you want to "reinvent the wheel" ? You should read about creating components in Joomla docs and MVC - http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to enable Joomla!'s SEF from the **Global Configuration**, and then write a **router.php** file for this component, if it doesn't have one.

See this: [Supporting SEF URLs in your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component)